# How I can copy/move folder and files recursive than x Days old in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, recursion, copy, move, get-childitem

I want to copy files from A to B in Powershell. For this I want to only copy Files that are older then $days. It works but if I have a Folder with old files and only one file is new, the function doesn't copy the folder with the old files.

Here my **code**:

```
function copyFolder($source,$destination,$lastwrite){

    foreach($Files in Get-ChildItem $source -Recurse | Where {$_.LastWriteTime -le $lastwrite}){

         foreach($File in $Files){

                if($File -ne $NULL){

                     Copy-Item $File.Fullname -Destination $destination -Recurse
                }
         }
    } 

}

#Anfangspunkt (A)
$path = "C:\Users\tarasov_w\Downloads"
#Ziel (B)
$destination = "C:\Users\tarasov_w\Desktop\ps_test"

$Now = Get-Date
$Days = 5
$LastWrite = $Now.AddDays(-$Days);

copyFolder -source $path -destination $destination -lastwrite $LastWrite
```

Comment: This worked correctly for me if I understand what it's supposed to do.  Whether there is a new file or not, the old files were copied.  What version of Powershell are you running?  I am using Powershell 4.0.

Comment: I would suggest using robocopy.

Comment: i want do this without robocompy